# Как вывести данные в html? angular

Tags: angular, angular10

Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести данные в хтмл?
Есть массив авторов в компоненте

```
authors: Observable<AuthorModel[]> = this.storeAuthor$.pipe(select(listAuthors));
```

Пробую вывести вот так

```
<div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label class="">Author</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="authors" multiple>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let author of authors | async" [value]="author.id">
                        {{author.name}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
```

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. У вас уже листится ваш массив `authors`.